# Can we use Lync/Skype SDK in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, skype, lync, skype-for-business

I am new to programming with SDK so I wanted to check what is the best way to have an automated interaction between my Java application and Lync.

I did some research online and found this link were you can download and start using the SDK with visual studio.  but I want to use Eclipse IDE to do the programming.

SDK download link - https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=36824

Sandesh Jadhav

Comment: better create a maven project and use [skype](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadskypejavaapi15jar.htm) jar file as a sdk for eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This depends a little bit what you wish to perform and which application you wish to write as there exists multiple Lync / Skype for Business SDKs. Based on your posting it looks like you aren´t really sure where to start, so let me create a summary here where you can choose the right SDK from.*

With Skype for Business (former known as Lync) you have multiple options to choose from. However it depends if you wish to build an Server or an Client application:

[image]
(Source from Screenshot [here](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Whats-New-in-Skype-for-Business/Opportunities-with-the-Skype-Developer-Platform))

- [UCWA](https://ucwa.skype.com/) (is a RESTful Web API that acts on behalf of a single Skype for Business user)
- [UCMA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn454984(v=office.16).aspx) (is a .NET SDK that provides rich control over a Skype for Business server deployment. It enables applications to automatically route calls and messages, provide automatic responses (IVR or chat bots), record conversations etc.)
- Skype for Business / Lync Server SDK
- [Skype for Business Client (Desktop) API / Lync client managed API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj937254.aspx)
- [Skype for Business App SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/appsdk/skypeappsdk) (designed to work with your iOS and Android app)
- [Skype Web SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/websdk/docs/skypewebsdk) (set of JavaScript Web APIs and HTML controls that enable you to build web experiences that seamlessly integrate a wide variety of real-time collaboration)

However it depends what you wish to perform and for example if your java application is some kind of mobile one for example.

*Depending on your needs you might also have a look into the "[Microsoft Bot Framework](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/channel-inspector/channels/Skype/)".*

Comment: Thank you for the detailed note.

Comment: I want to use Skype for business and send and receive (read) chat on my machine using the locally installed client and I am not looking at any server interaction.

Comment: Then I think you should check the client SDK. Keep noted that there was a [Java SDK](https://github.com/taksan/skype-java-api), however that was dropped as there exists a better solution now.

Comment: Liked your option 'Skype for Business Client (Desktop) API / Lync client managed API' does this work with Java (Eclipse IDE)

Comment: what is the better solution you are talking about..  @BastianW

Comment: Thats not easy to tell as I do not know the project you wish to build. As beginning you might start with the web SDK. [here](http://www.matthewproctor.com/skype-web-sdk-sending-an-instant-message) is a cool example for sending messages.

Comment: Thank you for your time and patience.  I would like to use the local machine  client as entry point for my automation script. the actions I would like to do is read a incoming chat (script to read it).. and respond to the chat with our comments...  This is all I want to do.